# Retrieve records between hours

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following model (I'm using ruby on rails) :

```
  # MealSetting model
  # week_day:integer
  # pick_up_start_time:datetime
  # pick_up_end_time:datetime
```

I want to retrieve all the meals that are available in a certain time, a meal is available if the `pick_up_start_time <= current_hour` and 
`pick_up_end_time >= current_hour`.

`pick_up_start_time:datetime` and `pick_up_end_time:datetime` are actually dates but I'm only using the hours.

I have this query,

```
MealSetting
  .where('pick_up_start_time::time <= ? and pick_up_end_time::time >= ?', 
  Time.now.utc.strftime("%T"),
  Time.now.utc.strftime("%T"))
```

But it doesn't work because the dates in the database are stored in utc.

Comment: are you using mysql ?, if so, would you mind trying with: `.where('TIME(pick_up_start_time) <= TIME(?) and TIME(pick_up_end_time) >= TIME(?)', Time.now, Time.now)`

Comment: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain SQL and use the `now()` method.
Since you want to compare the hours inside the dates you can use the `date_part` function of postgres.

```
MealSetting.where("date_part('hour', NOW()) BETWEEN date_part('hour', pick_up_start_time) AND date_part('hour', pick_up_end_time)")
```

Comment: I get the logic, But I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't it return the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for scopes

```
class MealSettings < ApplicationRecord

  scope :ready_for_pickup,   -> { where("hour(pick_up_start_time) <= ?", Time.now.utc.hour) }
  scope :before_pickup_ends, -> { where("hour(pick_up_end_time) >= ?", Time.now.utc.hour) }

end

MealSettings.ready_for_pickup.before_pickup_ends
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to compare the dates I want to compare de hours inside those dates.

Comment: It says column "time" does not exist

Comment: @CarlosGuerrero whoops sorry, 1 more edit coming in hot

Comment: it gives this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function hour(timestamp without time zone) does not exist